# Weird toggle between functions, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery

First time I click, nothing. Second time, the first alert fires twice. Third time, the second alert fires twice, and the first one fires once. Fourth time, it gets even weirder. I guess I'm using toggle() wrong, but I don't see how. The code is

```
<button onclick="$(this).toggle(function(){alert(1)}, function(){alert(2)})">Play</button>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2uRKD/

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the [documentation for `.toggle()`?](http://api.jquery.com/toggle)

Comment: Damn, I was reading confusing with this one http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: there's another toggle, the event handler: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: I believe what LFS is using is the deprecated [`toggle event`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). It does seem to work though on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sDhDL/).

Comment: What is the modern replacement?

Comment: I don't think there is one. You'll probably need to track the current state somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toggle is a jquery event which toggles between alternative clicks and you do not need click event to bind to toggle.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/2uRKD/5/)**

```
$(function(){

  $('button').toggle(

    function() {
        alert(1);
    },

    function() {
        alert(2);
    });​
  });
```

Comment: Note that this [Toggle Event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) has been deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed completely in 1.9.

Comment: What are you using for a non-deprecated alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Toggle isn't used to toggle between 2 functions. It's to hide and show elements.

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2uRKD/4/

Comment: There are two toggle methods. One of which *is* used to toggle between 2 functions...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Html:

```
<button type="button">Play</button>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
​$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").toggle(function(){alert(1)}, function(){alert(2)}) 
});​
</script>
```

I have no explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

the form of the method that you are using is the [toggle event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). Effectively what this does is binds click handlers. So what you are doing is each time you click you are binding the toggle to the event. I'm not goign to try to understand the logic of what you are binding there, suffice to say it is wrong. :)

What you would want to do instead is something like:

```
$('.ToggleButton').toggle(function(){alert(1)}, function(){alert(2)})
```

and this should go in your document.ready or equivalent.